# Printing Assembly Variable in GDB

Tags: c, assembly, gdb

I don't have the full source code but an object file with symbols. There's a read line:

```
=> 0x080489cd <+169>:   call   0x8049275 <read_line>
   0x080489d2 <+174>:   mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x080489d5 <+177>:   call   0x8048d59 <phase_1>

in the function:
 8048d59:   55                      push   %ebp
 8048d5a:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048d5c:   83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
```

I put a b in the first line and also added one to the function name to be sure.  After entering "1" tried `p *(char**)$esp` and I get:

```
0x80489da "\350\355\006"
```

which is not what I was expected. I was expected to see "1". I also tried:

```
gdb x $esp
0xbffff0cc: 0x080489da

gdb x *0xbffff0cc

0x80489da <main+182>: 0x0006ede8
```

Comment: You say you have an object file with symbols. Do you know if it was compiled with `gcc -g`, i.e. with debugging info. You can recover 100% of the source code pretty quickly if this is the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are breaking on the first like of the function (I assume that's what you mean by: "I put a b in the first line") then what you're seeing is the return address. It looks like you're actually seeing the return address from calling phase_1.

If what you're looking for is the first parameter try:

```
p *(char**)($esp+4);
```

Comment: I haven't made it out of phase_1. That second part is in the phase_1 section.  How do I get the result of an individual instruction?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "result of an individual instruction". Instructions do not have "results" per se. You can look at the location written to (memory or register). If all you want is the result of read_line however, I would really suggest you try the statement I provided. If it doesn't work tell me what it says.